# How to switch class when a tab is clicked using google_nav_bar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using [google_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/google_nav_bar) and [line_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/line_icons) from pub.

I have 3 classes named Home(), Likes(), Profile(). I want to switch classes when a bottom navigation bar tab is clicked, I have made a list of the classes, but I'm not sure how to change the classes when a tab is clicked.

Here is the code I have so far:

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
    }
    
    class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
      int _page = 0;
    
      final screens = [
        Home(),
        Likes(),
        Profile()
      ];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
          bottomNavigationBar: GNav(
            rippleColor: Colors.grey[300],
            hoverColor: Colors.grey[100],
            gap: 8,
            activeColor: Colors.black,
            iconSize: 24,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
            color: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              GButton(
                icon: LineIcons.home,
                text: 'Home',
              ),
              GButton(
                icon: LineIcons.heart,
                text: 'Likes',
              ),
              GButton(
                icon: LineIcons.user,
                text: 'Profile',
              ),
            ],
            selectedIndex: _page,
            onTabChange: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _page = index;
              });
            },
          ),
          body: /*new Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: _page == 0
                ? Home()
                : _page == 1
                    ? Likes()
                            : Profile(),
          ),*/
          Center(
            child: screens.elementAt(_page),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I would like to navigate the bottom navigation bar to the Likes() class when the second tab is clicked and navigate to the Profile() class when the third navigation bar is clicked..

Comment: what is `GNav` in your widget.

Comment: its from google_nav_bar a type of bottom navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working fine. Replace `Tab` widget with different widgets like `Home(), Likes(), Profile().`.

Now it will be like

```dart
class Tab extends StatelessWidget {
  final int tab;
  const Tab({
    Key? key,
    required this.tab,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("$tab"),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  int _page = 0;

  final screens = const [Tab(tab: 1), Tab(tab: 2), Tab(tab: 3)];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      bottomNavigationBar: GNav(
        rippleColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
        hoverColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
        gap: 8,
        activeColor: Colors.black,
        iconSize: 24,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
        color: Colors.black,
        tabs: const [
          GButton(
            icon: LineIcons.home,
            text: 'Home',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: LineIcons.heart,
            text: 'Likes',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: LineIcons.user,
            text: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        selectedIndex: _page,
        onTabChange: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _page = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: screens[_page],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does it solve in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. Just add your Widgets in your classes

Your `BottomBar` Widget.

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Home(),
    Likes(),
    Profile(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 20,
        title: const Text('GoogleNavBar'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 20,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 8),
            child: GNav(
              rippleColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
              hoverColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
              gap: 8,
              activeColor: Colors.black,
              iconSize: 24,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
              color: Colors.black,
              tabs: [
                GButton(
                  icon: LineIcons.home,
                  text: 'Home',
                ),
                GButton(
                  icon: LineIcons.heart,
                  text: 'Likes',
                ),
                GButton(
                  icon: LineIcons.user,
                  text: 'Profile',
                ),
              ],
              selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
              onTabChange: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = index;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Your `Home` Class

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Home',
    );
  }

}
```

> Your `Likes` Class

```
class Likes extends StatelessWidget {
  const Likes({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Likes',
    );
  }
}
```

> Your `Profile` Class

```
class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  const Profile({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Profile',
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a better switch use IndexedStack:

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  int _page = 0;

  final screens = [
    Home(),
    Likes(),
    Profile()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      bottomNavigationBar: GNav(
        rippleColor: Colors.grey[300],
        hoverColor: Colors.grey[100],
        gap: 8,
        activeColor: Colors.black,
        iconSize: 24,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        tabBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        color: Colors.black,
        tabs: [
          GButton(
            icon: LineIcons.home,
            text: 'Home',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: LineIcons.heart,
            text: 'Likes',
          ),
          GButton(
            icon: LineIcons.user,
            text: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        selectedIndex: _page,
        onTabChange: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _page = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _page,
        children: screens,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```